# Issue with JSON null handling in Newtonsoft wih API

Tags: c#, api

I have some code and when it executes, it throws a `NullReferenceException` saying:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.this[string].get returned null
```

Code:

```
public static List<Tuple<string, string, string>> europeData(string url){

        var aTuple = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>> { };
        string airTemperature= "";

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        var data = c.DownloadString(url);
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);

        foreach (var result in o["daily"]) {
            foreach (var result2 in result["temp"]) {
                airTemperature = o["day"].ToString();
            }
        }

        List<Tuple<string, string>> icon = convertIcon(conditionCode);

        foreach (var tuple in icon){
            aTuple.Add(Tuple.Create(formatEuTemperature(airTemperature), tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2));
        }
        return aTuple;
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Edit:  DATA EXAMPLE

```
 "daily": [
    {dt": 1595268000,
  "sunrise": 1608124431,
  "sunset": 1608160224,
  "temp": {
    "day": 278.14,
    "min": 273.15,
    "max": 279.4,
    "night": 273.15,
    "eve": 275.82,
    "morn": 275.35
  },
  "feels_like": {
    "day": 273.53,
    "night": 270.26,
    "eve": 271.89,
    "morn": 272.11
  },
},
...
},`
```

Comment: Would you be able to share an example of the API response? So that we can better help.

Comment: You are doing wrong many things, even if you fix o["day"] like said in answer, this code can still fail in so many places. You are making to many assumptions and no checks working with external data, this code can be acceptable like excersice but not even close for production.

Comment: Data example added. This code not for production its just for education.

Comment: Why don't you just deserialize into an object model?

Comment: What is the cost of an [mre], why do we have butchered Json?

Comment: Is the JObject.Parse also for education? Would it be easier to use a Poco class representing the data? https://dotnetfiddle.net/sbxn6L (3min of copy past on smarphon)

Answer (score 1):

o["day"] should probably be result2["day"] judging from the layout of your loops.

Having an example of the data you're working with would make it easier to answer.